# Screen Share From Ubuntu Desktop To Mobile Device

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I'm very much still a beginner when it comes to networking so I might be asking a completely ridiculous question, but if someone could stop me now and let me know whether or not it's possible that would be greatly appreciated.

As part of a project I'm trying to have remote access via Bluetooth to a gateway that's running Ubuntu desktop. From my research over the past few days I've found that a number of things are possible via Bluetooth:

- Sharing internet connection to mobile
- Casting audio/video from Ubuntu desktop to mobile
- Remote access (control only) from mobile (e.g. via [pRemoteDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pierre.remotedroid.client&hl=en))

I haven't been able to find any resource related to my specific use case regardless of what combination of search terms/phrases I use.

My question is whether or not it's possible to screen share (i.e. both view and control remotely) Ubuntu => Android/iOS/WP or, failing that, to cast the output from the desktop client to the mobile screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try something as simple as installing team viewer on both the client and the host.  And then you could start a session on your mobile device into your host device.

Comment: Yes, we actually messed around with Team Viewer for a while, and that was about as close as we came to finding an application that provides the functionality we're looking for. This is essentially going to be for accessing gateways you might not be able to reach (up high) so some simple way of connecting to them (like Bluetooth) was what I was looking for, but it seems like it might not be feasible (at least not with remote access functionality), which is fine too! There's always another solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I know you want to connect to an ubuntu machine, but let's say you used windows for a second. You could then use android remote pc http://androidremotepc.com (for android phones) to use Bluetooth to initiate a connection from your android phone to your windows pc. (You may have to pay for it though)

Comment: You're right, though, installing TeamViewer with customised TeamViewer ID's/passwords for each gateway device before they're set up is definitely a possible solution. Thanks for the suggestion.

What you just mentioned sounds interesting, I'll have a look and let you know.


Edit: Ahh yes, we actually had a go of this program already, and while it can be used to remotely control input but there's no way to capture the output.

Comment: Alright... good luck on your research AJ